# How to smoothly change x coordinate of an svg element?

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs, svg

I want to change the x1 and x2 of my svg line in 2 seconds. I do nbot know how I can do this transition. Can you help me with it please? :)
Here is my svg element:

```
 <svg height="50" width="1400">
   <line x1="{{xValue}}" y1="{{yValue}}" x2="{{x2Value}}" y2="{{y2Value}}" style="stroke:rgb(255, 0, 0);stroke-width:2;transform: "></line>
</svg>
```

This is the code in my js (angular) is which I am first setting the initial values of the svg coordinates. and then I want to change them through the svgLineFunc function.

```
    $scope.xValue = 40;
    $scope.yValue = 15;
    $scope.x2Value = 140;
    $scope.y2Value = 15;

    $scope.svgLineFunc = function (newValue) {

        $scope.xValue = newValue;
        $scope.x2Value = newValue + 140;

    };
```

but I want this change to be done smoothly like it is done with the css transition!!!

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Both `jquery` and `angularjs` have `animation` methods which you can use. if you can make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) sample, maybe we can help you with your code